# MVC validation created on fly is not working in ASPX view and working in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am having input element and on a button click i am creating a form on fly and placing the input inside the form and define form validation using the following code.

```
Sys.Mvc.FormContext._parseJsonOptions({
                Fields: [{
                    FieldName:  "IDsiValue1",
                    ReplaceValidationMessageContents: true,
                    ValidationMessageId: "IDsiValue1Error",
                    ValidationRules: [{ ErrorMessage: this.get_grid().get_LocalizedStrings().filtervalidationerror, ValidationParameters: { min: this._findMinRange(this._currentFilterColumn.type), max: this._findMaxRange(this._currentFilterColumn.type) }, ValidationType: "range"}]
                },

                FormId: "IDsiCustomForm",
                ReplaceValidationSummary: false
            });

Sys.Mvc.FormContext.getValidationForForm($("#" + gridid + "siCustomForm").get(0)).validate('submit')
```

However this validation works properly in razor view (CSHTML) and whereas in ASPX validation is not working properly i.e whatever i type validation error is thrown.

Thanks.